# Spring Security and FirebaseAuthenticationFilter causing Infinite Loop Issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security

I have set up a security configuration with Spring Security and Firebase for my application. However, I am facing an issue where the doFilterInternal method of my FirebaseAuthenticationFilter is being called in an infinite loop, resulting in a deadlock in the application.

Here is my Spring Security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    public SecurityConfig() {
        InputStream serviceAccountStream = SecurityConfig.class.getResourceAsStream("/google-services.json");

        FirebaseOptions options = null;
        try {
            options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                    .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccountStream))
                    .setDatabaseUrl("xxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
                    .build();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                        //.requestMatchers("dddd").permitAll()
                )
                .addFilterBefore(new FirebaseAuthenticationFilter(userDetailsService), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }


}
```

And here is the code for my FirebaseAuthenticationFilter:

```
public class FirebaseAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FirebaseAuthenticationFilter.class);

    private final UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    public FirebaseAuthenticationFilter(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        logger.info("doFilterInternal called");

        // Extrayez le token du header de la requête
        String token = extractTokenFromRequest(request);
        if (token != null) {
            try {
                FirebaseToken decodedToken = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(token);

                String connedUserEmail = decodedToken.getClaims().get("email").toString();
                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(connedUserEmail);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication =
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                                connedUserEmail,
                                null,
                                Collections.emptyList());
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("erreur de connexion");
                //throw new Exception(e);
            }

            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }


    private String extractTokenFromRequest(ServletRequest servletRequest) {
        // Convertissez ServletRequest en HttpServletRequest
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;

        // Extrayez le token du header de la requête
        String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (header != null && header.startsWith("Bearer")) {
            return header.substring(7);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

When attempting to access my application, the FirebaseAuthenticationFilter seems to be continuously called, leading to an infinite loop. I have checked the Firebase token, but everything appears to be correct.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any suggestions for resolving this problem? Thank you in advance for your assistance!

I have reviewed my Spring Security configuration and FirebaseAuthenticationFilter implementation, ensuring that the Firebase token is correctly processed. I have also checked for any potential misconfigurations in my code. However, despite these efforts, the doFilterInternal method of my FirebaseAuthenticationFilter is still being called continuously, resulting in an infinite loop. I expected the authentication process to occur smoothly without entering into a deadlock situation.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. Thank you.